# How to make div follow/fixed with horizontal scroll, but not vertical?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a div stay fixed only with horizontal scroll but not vertical?

As you can see, when I scroll from left to right the top nav bar is fixed like it should.

[image]

Though as I scroll down, the top nav bar also follows, not as intended. It should remain at the top when the user scrolls down.

[image]

This is my CSS to achieve this, simply using `position: fixed;` and `width: 100%;`

```
/* Nav */
.nav {

  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;

  width: 100%;
}
```

I don't know whether I need to use JavaScript to achieve this.

Thank you

- Further code as requested,

```
  <!-- Nav -->
  <div class="nav">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="">

    <!-- Logout button -->
    <button class="logout-btn" id="logout_user">Logout</button>

    <!-- User's email -->
    <span id="users_email"></span>

  </div>
```

```
/* Logo */
.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```
/* Logout Button */
.logout-btn {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;

  margin-right: 30px;

  border: none;
  color: white;

  padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;

  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;

  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```
/* User's email */
#users_email {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;

  margin-right: 15px;

  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Donald Ducks solutions (both) results in the following. Although the nav bar doesn't follow when vertically scrolling it doesn't stretch across the screen and has a scroll bar inside it.

[image]

Comment: Can you share more of your code and a bit more on your problem ?

Comment: I would Like To help you but can you provide your more code

Comment: I don't know how providing any more would be of any relevance. It's just an image (logo), span and button inside a div (.nav), but sure I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript for this. You will only need css.

What you can use is this:

```css
.nav {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px 4px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This css code should work.

If it doesn't, remove `overflow` and try this instead:

```css
.nav{
    height: 60px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px 4px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This should be enough.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve the problem. See my original post for the result. Thanks for trying however.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body{
margin:0px;
padding:5%;
background:#000;
}
.wrapper{
margin:0px auto;
width:60%;
background:#ccc;
border:2px solid #fff;
}
.block{
width:100%;
height:30px;
overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: none;
}
.box{
font-size:15px;
fon-weight:normal;
color:#333;
padding:0px 10px;
width:12%;
float:left;
line-height:25px;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="block">
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div><div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
<div class="box">Testing</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
 body{
margin:0px;
padding:10%;
background:#000;
}
.wrapper{
margin:0px auto;
width:50%;
background:#ccc;
border:2px solid #fff;
}
.box{
width:100%;
height:250px;
overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: none;
}
.box p{
font-size:15px;
fon-weight:normal;
color:#333;
padding:2%;
line-height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a solution.